# Supra Database Abnormal Termination

Tags: cobol, hp-ux

I have a SUPRA Database (Version 2930) running on HP-UX B.11.31 U ia64, but suddenly the log shows this message:

7 190523 071547 R    -1  8880   1 cld_irupt    : received son term pid : value =       8913

7 190523 071547 R    -1  8880   1 cld_irupt    : analyzed abnormal end : value =         11

6 190523 071547 R    -1  8880   1 cld_irupt    : stopping database     : abnormal terminat.

8 190523 071547 R    -1  8880   1 e82_run_coor : after    WHILE loop   : term_flag is set

8 190523 071547 R 23580  8938  59 vreceive     : interrup after read   : stop or term set

And then the database shutdown, I have to restart and everything goes well.
I have running cobol and mantis applications, but I can't find if it is due to one of those processes or the Database itself fails to perform any task.

The value of the PID is different each time, after find out which process was running with that PID, we execute the process again and it works correctly, in fact all of them run daily.
I don't know what more can I do to solve this problem,It becomes more frequently.
Does anyone have experience with this problem?

Comment: Please update tags to reflect correct DB engine.

Comment: I suggest you contact Cincom [Access SUPRA customer portal…](https://supportweb.cincom.com/), register and log in.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I registered in the SUPRA customer portal.  I was hoping to find someone who had this problem before and maybe get some recommendations.